# Including C libs on linux

Tags: c, gtk

I've decided to learn GTK and write small app, however I can't properly install and so include it. I am supposed to include <gtk/gtk.h>, however my package manager (pacman) decided that GTK should be stored in /usr/include/gtk-4.0/gtk/gtk.h, but if I try to #include <gtk-4.0/gtk/gtk.h> it causes errors as gtk.h includes other gtk/*.h (and the same ptoblem with glib, cairo and so on). Am I supposed to manually move all needed libs to the standard path or the only way is to include it in compiler via pkg-config?

Comment: Use the `-I` (upper-case i) option when building, to dd non-standard include file paths to be searched. Like `-I/usr/include/gtk-4.0`

Comment: See https://www.gtk.org/docs/dev-tools/ e.g. **cc \`pkg-config --cflags gtk4\` hello.c -o hello \`pkg-config --libs gtk4\`** *Please note the back ticks.